# Is this a remix,compiler or an openzeplin bug?

Tags: solidity, remix, openzeppelin

I just wrote a simple code to test openzeplin Safemath library. I am using the latest version of remix ide and compiling for ^0.5.0. 
Remix is using 0.5.0_commit.1d4f565a compiler
The environment is JavaScript VM
EVM Version is the compiler default

The add function does not seem to be working in the code given below

I have tried x.sub(1) it throws an exception as expected, i have also tried initializing x to different values but still does not work.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
import "./SafeMath.sol";

contract SimpleStorage {
    using SafeMath for uint;
    uint x;

    event incremented(uint x);

    constructor() public{
        x=0;
    }

    function increment() public {
        x.add(1);
        emit incremented(x);
    }

    function get() external view returns (uint) {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Expected output is an increment by one on every call to the function but getting the same value every time. Emit also shows the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's your bug :)

Instead of `x.add(1)` try `x = x.add(1)`. Add function is not inplace, new value is returned and you need to assign the new value to `x`.

Comment: Thank you! I had been puzzled for quite some time.

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. Happy programming! @Zaid Munir